# Delphi-xe7 arduino tpapro ApdComPort read

Tags: delphi, arduino, usb, delphi-xe7

I want to read a string from my Arduino via Usb(Serial).
I made this script but it has a problem:

```
procedure TForm1.ApdComPort1TriggerAvail(CP: TObject; Count: Word);
var
msg:string;
I:word;
C:ansichar;
begin
msg := '';
for I := 1 to count do
begin
C := apdComPort1.GetChar;
if C = #7 = false then
begin
if C in [#32..#126] then
begin
  msg := msg + C;
end;
end;
end;
listbox1.Items.Add(msg);
msg := '';
end;
```

The problem is that the "count" isn't right.
For example, when i send "Backspace" this is the output:

```
Bac
kspace
```

But on the arduino serial monitor it works fine.
Does anyone know why the the "count" isn't right and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Remy said, when receiving data in serial communication you may have many events triggerin for the same string. In fact each byte *is* an event, but drivers usually buffer the data.

To know the end of your message you should add some char sequence at the end of this message. If you send the string from Arduino using `Serial.println()` instead of `Serial.print()`, then it will add a new line mark after the text. This way you just need to add the characters to the `ListBox1.Items.Text` property instead of using `Add` function. You need to allow the chars #10 and #13 to make this work.

```
procedure TForm1.ApdComPort1TriggerAvail(CP: TObject; Count: Word);
var
  C: AnsiChar;
begin
  while Count > 0 do
  begin
    Dec(Count);
    C := apdComPort1.GetChar;
    if C in [#32..#126, #10, #13] then
    begin
      ListBox1.Items.Text := ListBox1.Items.Text + C;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Also, if you do it this way, you don't need to send the bell character (#7).

Comment: Well, this will show up the result in list box, but what if you would like to work with the commands without `TStrings` collection ? You'd have to add some extra monitoring logic (or use e.g. the `TApdDataPacket` component for that).

Comment: What's the matter? I'm using a `String` type property. It could be a String variable, then when `C = #13` process the message and empty that variable.
But the original code in the question used a TListBox, so I kept using it. Also using a TString collection allow to save all the messages received.

Comment: My point was that you are relying on a `TStrings` collection and breaking the received stuff with it; e.g. the `TApdDataPacket` component was designed just for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming a 1-to-1 relationship between the *complete* data and the event.  There is no such guarantee.  It may take multiple events to receive the *complete* data. The event is simply reporting that there is *some* data available *at that moment*. In your example, you likely received an event for 3 characters, and then received a second event for the remaining 6 characters.  You called `Add()` twice, once for each portion of data, rather than once for the *complete* data.

As such, you have to analyze the data you are receiving, caching it as needed between events, and then call `Add()` only when you have *complete* data to display. For example:

```
var
  msg: string;

procedure TForm1.ApdComPort1TriggerAvail(CP: TObject; Count: Word);
var
  I: Word;
  C: AnsiChar;
begin
  for I := 1 to Count do
  begin
    C := apdComPort1.GetChar;
    if C <> #7 then
    begin
      if C in [#32..#126] then
      begin
        msg := msg + C;
      end;
    end else
    begin
      ListBox1.Items.Add(msg);
      msg := '';
    end;
  end;
end;
```